# using python reg exp match str

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble using python reg exp to match str from html.

```
 support= re.findall(r'<span id="cos_support-(\d)*">(\d)*</span>', unicodePage)
 print(support)
```

The ourput is

> ('9', '6') ('7', '4') ('6', '3') ('5', '4') ('1', '4') ('5', '3').

But in my notepad++, I using the reg to match the str. The output is this

```
<span id="cos_support-3102208">314</span>
```

I want to have this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression search will return groups surrounded by round brackets. In your case, you have two groups defined in your regex, and only these parts are returned every time there's a match.

To retrieve full match, you need to surround your entire regex with round brackets like this:

```
support= re.findall(r'(<span id="cos_support-(\d)*">(\d)*</span>)', unicodePage)
```

Also, you have a non-critical error in your regular expression. Instead of `(\d)*`, you should use `(\d+)`, as this will include the entire numeric sequence into a matched group instead of just a single digit, as well as require at least one digit to be present. So the resulting expression should look like this:

```
support = re.findall(r'(<span id="cos_support-(\d+)">(\d+)</span>)', unicodePage)
```

Finally, if you don't want to catch internal groups and only need the full match, you can get rid of their respective round brackets:

```
support = re.findall(r'(<span id="cos_support-\d+">\d+</span>)', unicodePage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
r'-(\d+).*?>(\d+)<'
```